# Android Studio - reference getAssets() as static context

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I am trying to create a class that read Json Value. The function in the `MainActivity` class works fine however, if I try to create a separate class file I get the error that: `non-static method getAssets() cannot be referenced as stain context`.

How can I solve this?

```
public class jsonClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Context mContext;

    static String loadJSONFromAsset(String file) {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open(file); //ERROR

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

    static String getJsonValue(String jsonFile, String anni, String level, String getValue) {
        String value = null;

        JSONObject object = null;
        try {

            // Seleziona il file Json
            object = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset(jsonFile));

            //Oggetto JSON per ogni anno
            JSONObject getEra = object.getJSONObject(anni);

            //Lista Livelli per ogni anno
            JSONObject getLevel = getEra.getJSONObject(level);

            //Ritorna Valore scelto per ogni Livello
            value = getLevel.getString(getValue);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting error ? show that code

Comment: Try removing the static keyword while declaring the class: loadJSONFromAsset

Comment: getting error here: `InputStream is = getAssets().open(file); //ERROR`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: You are welcome too.  I think the content has enough detailed info, and the title asks exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing the static `mContext` with a valid context, you should be able to write

```
       InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(file);
```

Comment: I have tried this however, when I call the class the app crashes `String text = jsonClass.getJsonValue("allLevels.json", "90s", "level1", "text");`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as well using `public` and no `static`.

```
public static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context mContext, String file){

        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(file); 
}
```

Comment: If I do this I get an error on MainActivity to `make getJsonValue static`

Comment: If static do as follows:

Comment: it crashes `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.g`

Comment: Try this: `context.getResources().getAssets()`

Answer (score 0):

Your have declared class `loadJSONFromAsset` as a static class. This is creating the Error because when you are calling the method `getAssets()` the class InputStream is not static.
Check this link to get more info

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html
```

As you can see from the link, the InputStream class is actually
 `public abstract class InputStream extends Object implements Closeable`. Since this class is not static, you cannot use its method in a static class.

Comment: Ok thanks, And is there another way of doing this then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are in a static context. To get out of it create an instance of your class jsonClass in you main activity and get rid of all the "static"s in you jsonClass. Then call getJsonValue on the instance of the jsonClass.

in main class:

`jasonClass jclass= new jasonClass();
jclass.getJsonValue(....);`